# Static class for retrieve session bean in Spring and JSF

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I need a session bean accesible for service and data access layers but I don't want inject it in every object.

I don't want this:

```
 <!-- a HTTP Session-scoped bean exposed as a proxy -->
    <bean id="userPreferences" class="com.foo.UserPreferences" scope="session">

          <!-- this next element effects the proxying of the surrounding bean -->
          <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </bean>

    <!-- a singleton-scoped bean injected with a proxy to the above bean -->
    <bean id="userService" class="com.foo.SimpleUserService">

        <!-- a reference to the proxied 'userPreferences' bean -->
        <property name="userPreferences" ref="userPreferences"/>

    </bean>
```

Is it posible to create a static class for retrieving the session bean of the current request?

Something like this:

```
 <!-- a HTTP Session-scoped bean exposed as a proxy -->
        <bean id="userPreferences" class="com.foo.UserPreferences" scope="session">

              <!-- this next element effects the proxying of the surrounding bean -->
              <aop:scoped-proxy/>
        </bean>

Public Class sessionResolver{

  public static UserPreferences getUserPreferences(){

  //Not real code!!!
  return (UserPreferences)WebApplicationContex.getBean("userPreferences")
  }

}
```

Comment: I put mock code in getUserPreferences because I think it can't be done in spring configuration but I prefer config instead of code, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this works and I don't have a way to try it right now, but how about this:

```
public static UserPreferences getUserPreferences(){

    return (UserPreferences) ContextLoader.getCurrentWebapplicationContext()
                                            .getBean("userPreferences");
}
```

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks! At least, I now know how to retrieve webApplicationContext from anywere of my code. XD

Comment: @user551263 but I think it probably won't work with request or session scope. I think these scopes only work inside web controllers. But it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Define a helper class like UserPrefHelper.java

```
public class UserPrefHelper {
  private static com.foo.UserPreferences userPrefs;
  private void setUserPrefs(com.foo.UserPreferences userPrefs) {
     this.userPrefs = userPrefs;
  }
  private static UserPreferences getUserPrefs() {
     return userPrefs;
  }
}



 <!-- a HTTP Session-scoped bean exposed as a proxy -->
<bean id="userPreferences" class="com.foo.UserPreferences" scope="session">

      <!-- this next element effects the proxying of the surrounding bean -->
      <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>

<!-- a singleton-scoped bean injected with a proxy to the above bean -->
<bean id="userPrefHelper" class="com.foo.UserPrefHelper">

    <!-- a reference to the proxied 'userPreferences' bean -->
    <property name="userPreferences" ref="userPreferences"/>

</bean>
```

Then use that helper class in your classes directly and that's all. It will turn you a proxied UserPreferences object every time and method execution will be delegated to session scoped bean.

```
public void test() {
     UserPreferences userPrefs = UserPrefHelper.getUserPrefs();
    //That's all. Don't worry about static access and thread safety. Spring is clever enough.                      
}
```